# Сhanging image in QSvgWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt

I have a SVG widget

```
icon = QSvgWidget('path/icon.svg')
icon.setFixedSize(72, 72)
```

How I can change `icon`'s image?

Comment: svg is vector based so you need to: change the attributes of the vector, color, strokes etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how I can change it.

```
icon.setStyleSheet(f'image: url(cache/{str(app)}/icon.svg)')
```